Error 500 during connecting Woocommerce via Make.com
I am trying to create a Woocommerce connection via Make.com but I am receiving an error 500 (as you can see in the attached screenshot). I have tried reset or change Woocommerce permalinks but nothing helped.

Also I have tested the API connection via Postman (download orders via this URL: https://svetvramu.cz/wp-json/wc/v3/orders) and it worked perfectly (200 OK). consumerKey and consumerSecret were both the same.
I have discussed the issue with my server provider, IP address of Make.com are not blocked. Also I have discussed the issue with Make.com support, they told me it is necessary to contact Woocommerce support.
Also Make.com provided the request which is trying to establish connection.
curl 'https://us1.make.com/api/v2/connections?inspector=0&teamId=133681' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
  -H 'cookie: rl_page_init_referrer=RudderEncrypt%3AU2FsdGVkX1%2B1SwjgQ5aR0xP5XGFhYI4hmFsTX%2Br5Flw%3D; rl_page_init_referring_domain=RudderEncrypt%3AU2FsdGVkX1%2F%2F5rb7glRs%2BMBSLG0iJY6F3ghk6%2F2nGMw%3D; _ga=GA1.1.1087030648.1700560957; gb_anonymous_id=50e849ec-cab0-4f91-acba-084103d0f75d; _fbp=fb.1.1700560959636.1416449227; make_user_id=358037; __stripe_mid=a745c31b-e65c-49b3-a519-6a044dc940c5ace649; _hjSessionUser_2919042=eyJpZCI6IjM3YzY2Y2FjLThlODYtNTg0ZC1iY2U0LTZmOGZlNjQ1YzY2YyIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE3MDA1NjA5NTcyMjksImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; no_legacy_organizations:358037=true; _ga_MY0CJTCDSF=GS1.1.1714006987.473.1.1714006988.59.0.0; _gcl_au=1.1.1831238289.1716281944; cf_clearance=SAcdG.5sFmpDxhi5Jrf0H3fI.2fpdNtTu8LYNOSOGmo-1718672017-1.0.1.1-y7Lz2B0.2RhQspj7LxARPT_BUPlZuq6OsD5i5aYwBZgD6qTBU8bIU4u6bVzDGclblyEjTVyTGtXE_FhK1oejPw; _gcl_gs=2.1.k1$i1718700720; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2024-06-27T06:26:17.708Z; XSRF-TOKEN=82a587a0-3e52-40da-95bb-3f3029442efb; sid=s%3AticUQWlVSvHt0PRTfoUU2ni9chYlOeZ3.e6ac9ff1774fdc59.XIWmci1KIOZW9LOKMQ%2Fm25iIurPC%2F6EiRxYdQLQVrnI; hq_sid_copy=byqSK_JH7ZWSfKAruzuoWo22yPZI-8dG.e6ac9ff1774fdc59; zone:358037=%7B%22orgId%22%3A338770%2C%22userId%22%3A358037%2C%22zoneId%22%3A2%7D; make_session_id=1719828706; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Mon+Jul+01+2024+15%3A42%3A46+GMT%2B0530+(India+Standard+Time)&version=202306.1.0&browserGpcFlag=0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=12d0214e-4414-4bc9-89a7-c37e940b0faf&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0004%3A1%2CC0002%3A1&geolocation=IE%3BL&AwaitingReconsent=false; rl_user_id=RudderEncrypt%3AU2FsdGVkX18o4D134R%2BdY3vqQs%2FDLiD4QQkgXSokUNc%3D; rl_trait=RudderEncrypt%3AU2FsdGVkX1%2FYdqd7%2FhB4rQdMqN7nbXPlESISvW3X1tFXLyqUjgajUCYxkXGKAX9ml%2FkdYXLVPVIdVap7kCAXpg%3D%3D; rl_group_id=RudderEncrypt%3AU2FsdGVkX1%2FrlI3bBl9nQWsoMp3w59xZLhDxOThZ6AU%3D; rl_group_trait=RudderEncrypt%3AU2FsdGVkX1%2BhLtEl4FmbrCDC1gxXZxqVUUU7%2B4j0LcM%3D; rl_anonymous_id=RudderEncrypt%3AU2FsdGVkX18Vh%2Fly1NKZHTpC3Q7m73DYm0SKmIjj9wxwir7NvpbxqbEjuHuzbU6KJx9469l3pT2%2BMxLBZjvh%2Bw%3D%3D; rl_session=RudderEncrypt%3AU2FsdGVkX1%2BM2TB9oqRzg2TcScr8XspoUuiVUs1SdXY2ByCU6i%2BYTC%2Bc%2Ff1VUhZMvv9VTm%2BVVqCNpfpBLDPzzD%2FJrqTr1MtIltuY4gQm84ibTuRTEbfY7saFtXyLuB7%2FfHGaZOGBg5AJEfPaoqU0Yg%3D%3D; _rdt_uuid=1719469578879.17f30814-204c-49ab-a767-98c45108844c; __stripe_sid=4a266f2a-b036-42e2-b311-342d1b8c9d125e0f69; _uetsid=c9cdc5a036e011ef9d1ad929717f8bce; _uetvid=9765a74036eb11efb47db5a50892acf3; _ga_MY0CJTCDSF=GS1.1.1719881428.13.1.1719881512.60.0.0; userId=%7B%22userId%22%3A358037%2C%22expires%22%3A%222024-07-02T23%3A56%3A13.617Z%22%7D; __cf_bm=hLQ6C1.2nABKr.tZ4jiuay7JFx.Uht7_GYqSAr_vfhY-1719881787-1.0.1.1-I4RSmjtSjmfL2GKvu7zSQd9Jz15H6ClbXX1TCsnoWtq5_tzQv5FgkLXTWqtveL.L3ptMwI4wLUYPbtSDaj.JgQ; _dd_s=logs=1&id=7387e497-5911-4c44-9eaf-fb54e84ecc0d&created=1719881425789&expire=1719882712850' \
  -H 'imt-remote-formula: 1' \
  -H 'origin: https://us1.make.com' \
  -H 'priority: u=1, i' \
  -H 'referer: https://us1.make.com/133681/scenarios/add' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-android-device: -7628fb0' \
  --data-raw '{"accountName":"My WooCommerce connection","accountType":"woocommerce2","consumerKey":"XXX","consumerSecret":"XXX","domain":"https://svetvramu.cz"}'

Do you have experience with something similar?
Big thanks to anyone who can help me, I do not have a clue where the problem could be.

What is the output when you execute the curl on a command line (Please add -v as parameter, so start with curl -v  'https://us1.make.com/api .......

Generally a HTTP 500 is a server error, but from this info I would not know if make.com is throwing the error , or svetvramu.cz

I am attaching the output (unfortunately it is necessary to show you output as a screenshot because of the length). @Luuk
https://svetvramu.cz/wp-content/uploads/2024/07/Snimek-obrazovky-2024-07-03-v-9.33.06.png

When it is on an external (to stackoverflow.com) link, or in an image format, I will not look at it .... (One exception maybe https://pastebin.com/ )

@Luuk Understand, here you go: https://pastebin.com/30H2fZ85
Thank you.

there is no HTTP 500 in your patebin, but a HTTP 401.... Last line says {"detail":"Access denied.","message":"User is not logged in.","code":"IM015","suberrors":[] which should be pretty informing info.
